# Hide some item dividers in recyclerview using DividerItemDecoration

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, divider

I have a recycler view with multiple item types and i want to hide selected dividers (from image). I'm currently using DividerItemDecoration for both horizontal and vertical decoration.

```
DividerItemDecoration verticalDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), DividerItemDecoration.HORIZONTAL);
verticalDecoration.setDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.divider_2dp));
DividerItemDecoration horizontalDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
horizontalDecoration.setDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.divider_2dp));

mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(verticalDecoration);
mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(horizontalDecoration);
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe your divider lines should rather be part of the viewholder xml, so you have control over the per-item separators.

Answer (score 3):

As Micha commented on your answer, you should remove the handling of your dividers in the level of your Class and add it in the Adapter views. Add to your viewholder xml a view:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/light_grey"/>
```

either horizontal or vertical per your liking and control its visibility through a condition in the adapter:

```
View tipsDivider = itemView.findViewById(R.id.divider);
myViewHolder.divider.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

In particular to your question, do NOT include a divider for the outer edge of your rows and also hide it when you have a title ("ADVANCED") or when it's about the element at the `position == arraylist.size() - 1;`

Hope that helps whoever lands at this question as well.